Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{-1}\sin(nx)$ as a distribution in $\mathcal D'（\mathbb R）$

As a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$, $u_n(x) = x^{-1} \sin(nx)$, compute the limit in the distribution space $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ of $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n$.

I have solved the cases of $u_n(x)=\sin(nx)$ and $u_n(x)=n\sin(n|x|)$. (I can solve them just by-- writing down their antiderivative and integrating by parts.) But now the question is I cannot find the formula of antiderivative of $x^{-1}\sin(nx)$. So the process cannot be done.
I also consider to use Maclaurin's series to deal with it. But it's also failed.

Hint: Decompose $\varphi\in\cal D$, as
\begin{equation}
\varphi(x) = \varphi(0)\psi(x) + x \theta(x)
\end{equation}
where $\psi\in\cal D$ and $\forall x \in [-1, 1], \psi(x) = 1$ and $\text{supp}(\psi)\subset[-2, 2]$ and $\theta\in\cal D$.
Note that
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^1 \varphi(0)\psi(x)\frac{\sin (nx)}{x} d x = \varphi(0)\int_{-n}^n\frac{\sin(y)}{y} d y\longrightarrow \varphi(0)\pi
\end{equation}
Show that all the other terms tend to $0$ because if $f\in C^1([a, b])$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f(x)\sin(nx) d x \longrightarrow 0
\end{equation}
The final result is that $u_n \to \pi\delta_0$ in $\cal D'$.

I understand that you probably haven't studied the Fourier transform on distributions yet, but I anyway want to post how the limit can be found using Fourier transforms.
I will use the following definition of the Fourier transform:
$$
\mathcal{F}\{f(x)\} = \hat f(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, e^{-i\xi x} \, dx.
$$
The Fourier transform of $\mathbf{1}_{[-n,n]},$ the indicator function on $[-R,R],$ is almost $u_n$:
$$
\mathcal{F}\{\mathbf{1}_{[-n,n]}\} 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{[-n,n]} \, e^{-i\xi x} \, dx
= \int_{-n}^{n} e^{-i\xi x} \, dx
= \left[ \frac{e^{-i\xi x}}{-i\xi} \right]_{-n}^{n}
= 2 \frac{\sin \xi n}{\xi}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin \xi n}{\xi}
= \frac12 \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{F}\{\mathbf{1}_{[-n,n]}\}
= \frac12 \mathcal{F}\{\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbf{1}_{[-n,n]}\}
= \frac12 \mathcal{F}\{\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb R}\}
.
$$
Now we use the fact that $\mathcal{F}\{\delta\}=\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb R}$ and that $\mathcal{F}\{\mathcal{F}\{u(x)\}\}=2\pi\,u(-x)$ for any (tempered) distribution $u.$ This implies that $\mathcal{F}\{\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb R}\}=2\pi\,\delta.$ Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin \xi n}{\xi}
= \frac12 \, 2\pi\,\delta
= \pi\delta.
$$
